# Is this a valid use case for a One To Many polymorphic eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have the following models, Property, Building and Unit.
The relations between Property and Building are following:

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function building(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Building');
    }
}
```

and the Building model is like this.

```
class Building extends Model
{
    public function properties(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Property');
    }
}
```

In words, each property has one Building, and what I need is, that Each building of the specific property has its own Units. Buildings can have many Units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this situation is not a good use case for polymorphic relationships. let's say we have an album with music in it, so we have an albums_table and music_table. in our situation, users should be able to like or dislike both albums or music separately, so we create a like_table and make a polymorphic relation between music and albums. I think this example would help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explanation is much better than the one in the documentation.

Comment: glad it helped you